# Setting ImmutableID for O365 users

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm having difficulties creating a command that generates a new GUID into the user's immutableID field.

The command `Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "UPN" -ImmutableID New-GUID` seems to just use "New-GUID" as the immutable ID.

Ultimately I'd like to set it to all users so I was thinking something like this:

```
Get-Msoluser -All | ForEach-Object {set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -ImmutableID New-GUID}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that makes the New-GUID run.

Reason I'm doing this is cause O365 doesn't natively have an immutableID so I figured a random GUID would work for federation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To run the command, put it in parentheses, and to output the guid as a string, select it from the parentheses: `-ImmutableID (New-GUID).guid`

Comment: Ah, that's what it was. Such a rookie mistake. Thanks for that.